# Resistor Divider Project

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, voltage-divider

I have a question about a resistor divider circuit. PLease see my circuit below. I have to design 2 seperate circuits for the following 2 cases each with their specific requirements as shown. I am flexible on the resistor values R1, R2 & R3 and the Rail Voltage "V". I don't know if this is possible does anyone have any suggestions ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTNZSY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Case 1: 
\$ \text{    } V_{in} = 0.2 V  \Rightarrow V_{out} \ge 2.0 V \$ 
\$ \text{    } V_{in} = 0 V  \Rightarrow V_{out} \le 0.8V V \$

Case 1: 
\$ \text{    } V_{in} = 0.05 V  \Rightarrow V_{out} \ge 2.0 V \$ 
\$ \text{    } V_{in} = 0 V  \Rightarrow V_{out} \le 0.8V V \$

Comment: With std linear resistors only the Vout 'swing' must be <= the Vin swing. ie the problem is impossible. | If you are willing to add a transistor (or two) **OR** a low cost IC in each case the solution is simple. Are you?

Comment: If you use three resistors, are you limited to that topology? Or can you use a star configuration?

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? Maybe Vout should be on the R1-R2 node, and Vin on the R2-R3 node?

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if OP could return to clear up confusion. Clearly they were not that bothered about receiving help!

Comment: It is not possible for me to change the configuration so I guess it is impossible !

Comment: If you tell us what you are trying to achieve "big picture" we may be eable to help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all resistors have zero or positive resistance, and you can't buy resistors with a negative value then what you are asking is impossible.

It can easily be shown that:

$$ V_{out} = V_{in} \cdot \dfrac{R_3}{R_2 + R_3} $$.

Now \$ \dfrac{R_3}{R_2 + R_3} \leq 1 \$ , so \$ V_{out} \leq V_{in} \$